# Not able to pass values from model to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have 2 tables as is shown below

**teacher_student**

```
id  teacher_id   student_id
1     2           1
2     2           2
3     2           3
4     3           2 
5     3           4
```

**student**

```
id  name    age  
1    n1     12
2    n2     13
3    n3     14
4    n4     15
```

I wish to display all the students with their details for each teacher

For this I have the following code -

**Model**

```
public function get_assigned_student($teacherid)
    {
        $this->db->where('teacherid',$teacherid);
        $query = $this->db->get('teacher_student');
        $data = $query->result();

        foreach ($data as $main_data) 
            {
                $student_id = $main_data->student_id;  

                $this->db->where('id',$student_id);
                $main_query = $this->db->get('student');  
                $main = $main_query->result();
                //echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($main);
                //echo "</pre>";
                return $main;
            }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function request($teacherid)
    {
        print_r($this->student_model->get_assigned_student($teacherid));
    }
```

Issue is that when I am trying to print the result under controller (for testing purpose) I am getting only one value where as I should get a whole array. Can anyone please tell where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.....

Controller

```
public function request($teacherid)
    {
        $this->load->model('student_model');
        $records=$this->student_model->get_assigned_student($teacherid);
        print_r($records);
    }
```

Model

```
public function get_assigned_student($teacherid)
    {
        $this->db->where('teacher_id',$teacherid);
        $query = $this->db->get('teacher_student');
        $data = $query->result_array();
        $std = array();
        foreach ($data as $main_data) 
            {
                $student_id = $main_data->student_id;  

                $this->db->where('id',$student_id);
                $main_query = $this->db->get('student');  
                $main_data = $main_query->result_array();
                //echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($main_data);
                //echo "</pre>";
                $std = array_merge($std,$main_data);
            }
            return $std;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to return your value in array as per below code:

```
foreach ($data as $main_data) 
            {
                $student_id = $main_data->student_id;  

                $this->db->where('id',$student_id);
                $main_query = $this->db->get('student');  
                $main[] = $main_query->result_array(); 

            }
            return $main;
```

use **result_array()** instead of **result()**;

Try this may help you.

Thanks.

Comment: still getting the same issue

Comment: Check my updated code, just get return out of the loop and *main* would be taken as array. so it will give you final result with array. try this.